# SharePoint Online + CSOM: User Profile Property Privacy

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

It is known that SP 2013 left only two levels of User Profile Property Privacy: 'Only me' and 'Everyone'. Is there a way to grab the privacy level using CSOM?

The code below only gives me values itself:

```
var properties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor("i:0#.f|membership|xxx@yyy.onmicrosoft.com");
context.Load(properties, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
context.ExecuteQuery();
properties.UserProfileProperties.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like CSOM returns only those profiles fields that are accessible to everyone; so the question does not make sense.