# SharePoint Online: Cannot read user profile property via CSOM / PnP - why?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, pnp-powershell

We created a custom user profile property.

We want to read it's value via CSOM (or PnP, doesn't matter).

**We fail.**

Our property is **not** returned in the list of user profile properties. Other properties are returned. Our custom property is not.

This property is configured like this:

- multi-valued
- length: 3600
- Optional
- Visible to "Only me"
- Not Replicable
- Editable by user
- Not visible anywhere (used in SPFx solution)

[This other post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249374/custom-user-profile-property-not-visible-in-powershell-csom-until-populated-in-g) reports a similar effect. [This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/70801/9913) from 2013 claims that properties with visibility "Only me" cannot be retrieved via CSOM.

I want this to clear this up for SharePoint Online:

Is it possible to read each and every user profile property via CSOM? If not: What could be the reason for a property not being returned? I did not find any documentation so far.

Comment: what's the security context that's executing the CSOM? The same user, or a different user?

Comment: @DerekGusoff the SharePoint admin who wants to set the property for > 1000 users

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. I can see "Only Me" properties on users and their values while logged in as a tenant admin using this.

```
$act = Get-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account 'user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
$act.UserProfileProperties
```

`Get-PnPUserProfileProperty` uses CSOM under the covers. So if it's not coming back for you, there's either an issue with your code, or with your security context.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell you can read properties that have visibility set to only me .

For example you can try this ,

$propertyValue = $userprofile["ExampleProperty"].value

Answer (score 0):

As Get-PnPUserProfileProperty is also not working for me for the private properties, "Only Me" properties, I am sharing another way to get "Only Me" properties by using the web service /_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?wsdl. Below is a code sample

```
$adminUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com";
$accountName = "i:0#.f|membership|user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$fieldInternalName = "CustomField"

$creds = Get-Credential -Message "Please specify the admin credentials"

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($creds.UserName, $creds.Password)

$upService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri ("$adminUrl/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?wsdl") -UseDefaultCredential False
$upService.Credentials = $credentials
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($adminUrl)
$container = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
$container.SetCookies($uri, $credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($adminUrl))
$upService.CookieContainer = $container

$userData = $upService.GetUserProfileByName($accountName)
$userField= $upService.GetUserPropertyByAccountName("$accountName",$fieldInternalName).Values | select -ExpandProperty Value


Write-Output "------ User Fields"
Write-Output $userData

Write-Output "------ User Field ($fieldInternalName)"
Write-Output $userField
```